# System of eigenvalues of partial Laplacians and the Jacquet Langlands correspondence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, laplacian, quaternion-algebras

I'm looking for a precise reference. I could not dig it up in the original paper of Jacquet-Langlands.

Let $F$ be a totally real number field with $[F:\mathbb{Q}]=r$, let $B_1=M_2(F)$ be the split quaternion algebra and let $B_2/F$ be a non-split quaternion algebra. Choose orders $O_1\subseteq M_2(O_F)$ and $O_2=B_2(O_F)$. Assume that there exists coprime and square free totally positive elements $q,r\in O_F$ such that $O_1\otimes_{O_F} M\simeq O_2\otimes_{O_F} M$ where $M=F(\sqrt{q},\sqrt{r})$. Because of this assumption it follows that $B_2/F$ is split at each (real) infinite place of $F$ (and I guess that it should be ramified only at the primes dividing $qr$) and therefore, in particular we have
$$
B_1\otimes_F \mathbb{R}\simeq B_2\otimes_F \mathbb{R}
$$
Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be the reduced norm one elements in $O_1$ and $O_2$ respectively. Consider the hermitian symmetric spaces $X_1$ (resp. $X_2$) associated $B_1\otimes_F \mathbb{R}$ (resp. $B_2\otimes_F\mathbb{R}$).  Since $B_1$ is split this means that
$$
X_1\simeq X_2\simeq \mathfrak{h}^{r},
$$
where $r$ is the number of (real) places of $F$ which splits in $B_1$, namely $r=[F:\mathbb{Q}]$.

All of what I'm going to say in the following can probably be generalized to other Hilbert spaces (involving different flavor of weights) but let me keep it simple, so that we will be dealing with functions (so automorphic forms of weight $0$). Consider the Hilbert space $V_j=L^2(Y_j)$ where $Y_j=X_j/\Gamma_j$ ($j=1,2$). On each copy of $\mathfrak{h}$ in $X_j$, we have a partial Laplacian $\Delta_i^j$ ($1\leq i\leq r$, $j=1,2$) which acts on the quotient space $Y_j$. Note that because of our asumptions the locally symetric spaces $Y_j$ are "arithmetically close to one another" since $O_1\otimes_{O_F} M\simeq O_2\otimes_{O_F} M$; therefore some wishful thinking leads me to believe that the "discrete spectrum of their partial Laplacians" ( ----- this phrasing seems to be abusive to me if $r>1$ but for sure one can talk about the discrete spectrum of the full Laplacian namely $\Delta^j:=\sum_{i}\Delta_i^j$ ----- )  should be closely related to one another. Note that each partial Laplacian $\Delta_{i}^j$ ($1\leq i\leq r$, $j=1,2$) admits a unique self-adjoint extension to $V_j$. Here is what I think should be true but I could not find a reference for it:

**Tentative theorem**: Let $f\in V_2$ be a simultaneous eigenvector with respect to the partial Laplacians $\Delta_i^2$, i.e., 
$$
\Delta_{i}^2 f_2=\lambda_i f_2   \;\;\;  (1\leq i\leq r )   
$$
Then there exists an $f_1\in V_1$ with the same system of eigenvalues with respect to the partial Laplacians, i.e.
$$
\Delta_{i}^1 f_1=\lambda_i f_1   \;\;\;  (1\leq i\leq r )  
$$
Put in simple terms, the system of eigenvalues of the partial Laplacians on $Y_2$ is included in the system of eigenvalues of the partial Laplacians on $Y_1$.

**Remark** In principle one could prove explicitly such a result by integrating $f_2$ against a suitable theta kernel that would spit out $f_1$. Another approach could be to apply the Selberg trace formula.

**Q1** Assuming that the tentative theorem holds true, is it possible to get it from what is proved in the original paper of Jacquet-Langlands ("Automorphic forms on GL(2)")

**Q2** Is there an analogue of this theorem when $B_1\otimes_F \mathbb{R}\not\simeq B_2\otimes_F \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: I think the answer to both questions should be yes at least when the class number of $F$ is 1.  As I recall, along the lines of Q2, Strombergsson, Risager and others have considered an explicit trace formula comparison at least over $\mathbb Q$.  For Q1, the main point is to translate the archimedean information about automorphic representations into a classical formulation, but there is are complications when $F$ has non-trivial class number.